# How to replace all pictures by white rectangles?

Tags: spacing, graphics, draft, copyright

I have a long document (800 pages) with lots of pictures (300 pictures).
I have to produce a version of this document without the pictures (for copyright reasons).
The solution I have found so far is to use the `draft` mode of the `graphicx` package.

This solution is not fully satisfactory because it replaces the picture by a white rectangle with the name and location of the picture inside.

I would like to have only a white rectangle (of the same size as the picture, with a thin frame), but without any text inside.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well then, just patch `graphicx` to not output the text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}{\rlap}{\@gobble}{}{%
  \GenericWarning{}{Failed to patch \protect\Gin@setfile}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}

\end{document}
```

This code makes use of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the `\patchcmd` instruction: Does it matter for the command's operation that the command `\Gin@setfile` is located in the file `graphics.sty` rather than in `graphicx.sty`? (The former style file is loaded by the latter...) Separately, might it be safer to replace the assignment `\edef\@tempa{#3}`, in the preceding line of the code for the `\Gin@setfile` command, with `\edef\@tempa{}`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: This command works at macro level, not package level. You can read the etoolbox manual entry on this command. The `\@tempa` line can be left as it is, as it won't produce any side effects.

Comment: I guess my thought was that defining `\@tempa` to be empty, rather than have it contain the filename string, might be less intrusive than obliterating the next command. However, that's pure speculation on my part.

Comment: Thanks so much, this additional explanation is most useful.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, my last statement was incorrect :-S Yes, defining `\@tempa` to an empty value would work.

Answer (score 6):

My attempt was to redefine `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\LetLtxMacro{\oldincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{} m}{% \includegraphics[..]{...}
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}}\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \oldincludegraphics[height=3cm]{tiger} \quad 
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{tiger} \quad
  \fbox{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics[height=3cm]{tiger}}}
  \caption{This is a tiger}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: Remove all figures]

In the above example, the three images use (i) the original `\oldincludegraphics` command, followed by (ii) the newly redefined `\includegraphics` command, followed by (iii) an `\fbox{\phantom{\oldincludegraphics{...}}}` *without* the proper `\fboxsep` set, merely  as an illustration of what modification does. The grouping (via `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`) within `\includegraphics` makes sure that setting `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule` is only local.

[`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) provides an effective means to store (or copy) commands that have optional arguments (in this case, the original `\includegraphics` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)), while [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy means for specifying commands with (possibly intermixed) optional parameters through `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: You need to set `\fboxsep` to zero, or the frame will be slightly larger than the image.

Comment: I just used `\fbox` as an illustration, nor do I use the `draft` option of `graphicx`. I don't think the OP will use `\fbox`.

Comment: Very nice answer (I would have put the \fbox in the new command \includegraphics) ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Colas: So by "white rectangle" you mean `\fbox` filled with blank space equivalent to the original picture and not just a white rectangle with no border. Either way, I'll update my answer accordingly, for completeness. It actually makes more sense now.

Comment: What's the use of \begingroup and \endgroup ?

Comment: @Colas: `\begingroup` is the same as `\bgroup` or `{`. Similarly, `\endgroup` is the same as `\egroup` or `}`. These macros define the scope of certain changes within your code. For example, using `\renewcommand` within a group makes the change local, reverting back to the original definition after the end of the group. I've also updated my code to use a more appropriate `\fboxsep`; `-\fboxrule` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the package [`draftfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftfigure) to get the same result and modify the display of the switched off figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[allfiguresdraft]{draftfigure}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[draft=false,width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\setdf{content={This figure is switched off.}}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndréC Thank you. For more options and modifications for the ›switched off‹-figures see the documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/draftfigure/draftfigure.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For a quick hack, you can edit `graphics.sty` (in my case, it is `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty`) and find where is filename written inside the rectangle (here, it is line `223`, containing `\rlap{ \ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}%`). Comment it out, that's it.

Comment: Always edit a _copy_ of the original file, moved to a different location, rather than editing anything in the 'managed' TeX tree.

Comment: Admittedly; I was thinking of someone who needs to send the file away quickly, and will revert the change back right afterwards. The answer with etoolbox is much better.