# How can I remove the figures from a draft of my document?

Tags: floats, draft

I'm working on a research paper with many figures in it. To save paper, I would like to exclude the figures when I print drafts of the paper. Is there an easy way to do this (via command-line option, graphicx option, or something else)?

Comment: Related Question: [What measure can we use by LaTeX to control the print budget](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31268/what-measure-can-we-use-by-latex-to-control-the-print-budget/)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would simply use the `endfloat` package, which places all floats (`figure`s and `table`s) at the very end of the document. Then you can print only the leading pages with the text using the page range selection of your PDF viewer.

Alternatively, you can make LaTeX ignore all `figure` environments using the `comment` package:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{figure}
\let\endfigure\relax
```

See [How to exclude text portions by simply setting a variable or option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28096/how-to-exclude-text-portions-by-simply-setting-a-variable-or-option/28098#28098) for more details. A drawback here is that the label references won't work properly.

Comment: This gave me an issue `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` which can be fixed by adding an extra line: `\let\endfigure\relax` as stated here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29060/newenvironment-issues-with-environment-comment#comment72226_29073

Comment: Even though it's mentioned explicitly in the user guide of the `comment` package, it's worth repeating here: the `\excludecomment{figure}` method *requires* all `\end{figure}` directives to be on lines by themselves; nothing before `\end{figure}` on those lines, and nothing after `\end{figure}` either.

Answer (score 28):

Just add the `draft` option when you load your document class, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
```

You can also add the option to the `graphicx` package:

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

---

If you want to save space, you can do as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\relax}
```

Or if you want to use the `ifdraft` package, you can do thus:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifdraft{\renewcommand{\includegraphics}{\relax}}{\relax}
```

Comment: This option makes `graphicx` not include the images but prints frames with the same size so it doesn’t save space/paper but ink …

Comment: Note that your redefinition let things like `[scale=1]{file}` stay in the text. Better use `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{}` to gobble the arguments. The `\relax` is not necessary in this case, I guess.

Answer (score 18):

While the `draft` option replaces all graphics by frames with the same size, you may like to redefine `\includegraphics` so that it prints only the file name in an `\fbox` to save space/paper:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \fbox{#2}% print file name in a small box
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm]{imagefile}
    \caption{Caption text}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Notes**

- To suppress the file name box, too, replace the redefinition with `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{}`.
- The option `demo` lets `graphicx` print black boxes instead of searching the file to include it. It has nothing to do with your question but is useful for the demonstration ;-)
- The package `lipsum` provides blind text and doesn’t belong to the solution.

Comment: Cool solution. But if you redefine `\includegraphics` you don't need to the `demo` option, I think.

Comment: @NicolasVaughan: Sure but if one comments out the redefinition to see the difference it’s useful :-)