# Remove images from draft, even the ones defined in a {figure*}

Tags: graphics, draft

I'm trying to compile a draft of my .tex document, leaving out all the figures. The answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50912/13294), ie:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{figure}
\let\endfigure\relax
```

works for images included in a `\begin{figure}` block, but not for a `\begin{figure*}` one.

I tried adding a `\excludecomment{figure*}` line to the above block, but I get an error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\end{figure*}]
```

How can I exclude *all* images from the final PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this should work, but it's untested (you have not provided a minimal (non-)working example; if it does not work, let me know and I'll delete the answer; or, provide a MWE):

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{figure}
\let\endfigure\relax
\expandafter\let\csname figure*\endcsname\figure
\expandafter\let\csname endfigure*\endcsname\endfigure
```

The problem is that you can't work with names containing `*` out of the box. This is a "hack" to make the `figure*` environment do exactly the same as `figure`.

Comment: Works perfectly yo', thank you very much! (Sorry for not posting a MWE, will try not to be so lazy next time)