# How do you temporarily disable figures and tables from being compiled into output file?

Tags: tables, floats

I am currently writing my thesis and it has a 200 page limit **without** figures and tables.

Is there some way I can turn off tables and figures from being output, so I can check my page count, but without removing them from the code?

Please find here the style file I am using:

https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/thesis-class

Comment: You could use the `endfloat` package to print all `figure` and `table` environments on separate pages at the end of your document. Related: [How can I remove the figures from a draft of my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50904/134144)

Comment: If you use the `graphicx` package you can set the `draft` flag. `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`

Comment: Just load the `comment` package and add the instructions `\excludecomment{figure}`, `\excludecomment{table}`, `\let\endfigure\relax`, and `\let\endtable\relax` in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico ah thanks! That looks great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mico: I'm doing as you suggest, but I'm getting a compile error! Is there an alternative method I could try?

Comment: @Freeman - One more thing: The `comment` package does its thing by scanning for the strings `\end{figure}` and `\end{table}` (and all other excluded environments) *at the start of a line*. Hence, if one had the following input all on one line -- `\begin{figure}[h!] FIGURE \end{figure}` -- `comment` can't get its job done. Just a heads-up...

Comment: @Freeman - Please provide more information about the compiliation error(s) you say you're getting.

Comment: @Freeman - An excerpt from the user guide of the `comment` package: "The opening and closing commands [e.g., `\begin{figure}` and `\end{table}`] should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it."

Comment: @Mico: Ah, all my figures start \begin{figure}[H], perhaps this is the cause of the error? This is the error, I have little idea what it means: https://pastebin.com/tyPL5GTq

Comment: @Mico: Ah! I commented out everything in the file it mentioned and it worked! This is what is causing the problem - what on earth is the problem here? https://pastebin.com/qBYn4MXn

Comment: @Mico: Fixed it! Removed the "\textbf{}" at the end of the file. Thanks SO much for your help, I could haven't done that without your patient explanations. Many thanks.

Comment: @Freeman - The mysterious `\textbf{}` directives immediately after each `\end{figure/table}` definitely look like excellent candidates for removal...

Comment: @Freeman - If you're using the `[H]` placement specifier habitually, you're not using the LaTeX float mechanism properly; in fact, you're not using it at all. Do try to wean yourself off that habit, ì.e., use `[H]` only exceptionally.